# R crashes when install xlsx

Tags: r, crash, xlsx, r-xlsx

When I try to install the package `xlsx` I get fatal error and R server session disconnected.
It shows both the bomb with fatal error and server session diconnected even though I am just running it locally.
I am running r studio with r version 4.2.2 Patched.

Any known work arounds? It also did not work for version 4.2.2.

OS: windows 11

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: the operating system is windows 11

Comment: xlsx uses java libraries and thus depends on java & rjava. Is there something specific you need or would it be possible to use some other Excel library? If you have installed Tidyverse, you probably have a working readxl - https://readxl.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Thanks I will use that going forward